# is_array() distinction

Tags: php, arrays

I have a piece of code where a variable can either be an array or just a string.

```
if(!is_array($relation['display_name']))
{
    // do something with $relation['display_name']
}
else
{
    foreach($relation['display_name'] as $display_name)
    {
        // do the same with $display_name
    }
}
```

This of course works - but it's not very nice. And I would have to do it a lot of times. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your approach. What exactly do you want to improve?

Comment: Make a function instead.

Comment: "Beauty is in the eye of the beholder"

Comment: beauty is everything for a developer that knows someone might see his code one day :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
foreach((array)$relation['display_name'] as $display_name) {
     // do something with $display_name
}
```

Comment: Nice and short solution! Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't this cause errors when the `$relation` variable really cant be converted to an array?

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
if(!is_array($relation['display_name'])) {
    $relation['display_name'] = array($relation['display_name']);
}

# do your foreach here
```

Comment: +1: An additional tip would be that if one day you're working with keys, you can use array_key_exists() function instead :)

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you look into fixing the source of the problem.

Why is `$relation['display_name']` sometimes an array and sometimes not?

Problem fixing is better then patching the outcome.

That being said, I would create the following:

```
function transformToArray($mValue) {
    return (is_array($mValue)) ? $mValue : array($mValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write it much shorter with the ternary operator:

```
foreach ((is_array($a) ? $a : array($a)) as $val) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a bad way of handling this issue. Most of the PHP code I have seen handles stuff like this similar.

Answer (score 0):

If using >= PHP 5.3 you could try something like this. It will run the code on the element if it is singular or implicitly over all array members if an array.

```
function call($element, $func) {
    if (is_array($element)) {
       foreach($element as $value) {
           $func($value);
       }
    } else {
       $func($element);
    }
}

call($relation['display_name'], function($display_name) {
   // Anything you wanna.
});
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ySenCT).